# Why is git looking in the wrong directory for the git installation? (OS X)

Tags: git, osx-mavericks

I am new to OS X and cannot find anywhere how to fix this. I installed git but the installation was messed up and I had to remove it. I installed it using the latest git dmg file but whenever I type in

```
git
```

I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

That is because git is not installed in that directory and instead in /usr/local/bin/git

If I type in the entire path to the directory than I get the correct output.

So what did I do wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Check if it's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: This is what it looks like /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: There's probably a symlink somewhere pointing to /usr/bin/git or it's itself a broken link. What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/git`? Did you install it as part of Xcode command line tools?

Comment: No such file or directory. Yeah I installed it as part of the xcode command line tools but the I uninstalled it and tried installing it using just the dmg from git.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is over a year old but just for anyone who experiences this issue:

I had a similar issue after renaming the OS X provided git client and installing using Homebrew. I found the issue was due to the current terminal session. The OP has the correct paths so I wouldn't recommend editing the `/etc/paths` file.

If after running `which -a git` you see `/usr/local/bin/git` everything should be correctly configured, **open a new terminal** and you should be able to run `git` with no errors.

Running `which git` should now output `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: This right here. A Github mac app update killed git in my current terminal window. Closing the terminal altogether and reopening fixed the problem.

Comment: This is awesome! please highlight the line : "Open a new Terminal and try!"

Answer (score 3):

It's not in your `$PATH`.  It's installed in `/usr/local/bin/git` but your path only has

`/usr/local/git/bin`.  Fixing the path should work.

Answer (score 0):

edit the file `/etc/paths` and add a line `/usr/local/bin/`

```
 echo "/usr/local/bin/" >> /etc/paths
```

you may have to run this command with `sudo`.

Open a new terminal window and type `which -a git`. If you see `/usr/local/bin/git` listed, you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

this might happen if you change git installations (happened to me when I update git-gui).
opening new terminal solved the issue for me.